# Generic type sorting by nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following static class:

```
public static class SortFilter
{
    public enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }

    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Sort<TEntity, TKey>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, TKey> sorter, SortDirection d)
    {
        if (SortDirection.Ascending == d)
        {
            return entities.OrderBy(sorter);
        }
        else
        {
            return entities.OrderByDescending(sorter);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Sort<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, string sortParams)
    {
        string[] parameters = sortParams.Split('_');

        if (parameters.Count() == 1 || parameters.Count() > 2)
        {
            return entities;
        }
        else
        {
            if (parameters[1] == "ascending")
            {
                return Sort(entities, x => GetPropertyValue(x, parameters[0]), SortDirection.Ascending);
            }
            else if (parameters[1] == "descending")
            {
                return Sort(entities, x => GetPropertyValue(x, parameters[0]), SortDirection.Descending);
            }
            else
            {
                return entities;
            }
        }
    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
    {

        return obj == null ? null : obj.GetType()
                                       .GetProperty(name)
                                       .GetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

I can call the Sort method on a List like this (the User class has Id and Name properties):

```
users = SortFilter.Sort(users, "Name_ascending");
users = SortFilter.Sort(users, "Id_ascending");
```

So far, so good: that will work just fine.

However, let's say my User class also has a UserGroup property and that I want to sort my User list by the Name of that UserGroup. This call will obviously fail:

```
users = SortFilter.Sort(users, "UserGroup.Name_ascending");
```

given that UserGroup.Name is not itself a Type (therefore GetPropertyValue method will throw an exception).

Is there a way to make a generic enough Sort function that will take a collection and sort it by any number of nested properties sent as an argument? I have several Views with table data that should be sorted by any column the user clicks, in ascending or descending order. Having sorting and filtering code within the controller seems very dirty.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Linq sort method? You could just do `users = users.Sort(u => u.UserGroup.Name).ToList();` and not be reinventing the (sorting) wheel with your `SortFilter` class.

Comment: Mainly because I want to be able to call that method any time for any collection, not just for Users. Say I also have a Player and Team class in the application. I want to achieve this:
`players = players.OrderBy(p => p.Name);` as well as this
`players = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Team.Name)` with the same Sort method.

Comment: And why doesn't that work? Linq sort methods resolve whatever property or expression you insert. You could do `players = players.OrderBy(p => p.Parent.Team.Staff[0].Name.FirstName);` if you so inclined, or for example, people often get a random sort by doing `players = players.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`, which also works. So, sticking with my original question, why can't you just use Linq in your specific instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like always for string parameters for LINQ use [DynamicLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
//..

if (parameters[1] == "ascending" || parameters[1] == "descending")
{  
    return entities.AsQueryable()
                   .OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", parameters[0], parameters[1]))
}
else
{
    return entities;
}
```

Docs can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx) in `LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic Expressions.html`.

Nested properties are supported of course.